# How to count all combinations of 1 column against multiple columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have CSV exports of data for individual pieces in a collection that each have two initial columns: A & B.
Column A has topics and column B has 0+ tags for those topics separated by commas.
There exists a master list of all possible singular combinations of topics/column A and tags/column B, but each CSV export may one, more, or none of any particular combination and there can be many total combinations.
In the actual master list, there are about 20 topics and anywhere from 2 to maybe 50 tags per topic.

Master list example:

```
Topics/A Tags/B
   AA      XX
   AA      XY
   AA      XZ
   AB      VV
   AB      VW
   AB      VX
   AB      VY
   AB      VZ
   AC      YY
   AC      YZ
```

Individual piece CSV example:

```
Topics/A      Tags/B
   AA      
   AA           XZ
   AA         XZ, XX
   AA         XZ, XX
   AB         VV, VY
   AB           VY
   AB       VX, VV, VZ
   AB           VY
   AB   VZ, VW, VV, VY, VX
   AC           YY
   AC           YY
   AC           YY
   AC         YY, YZ
```

I want the final result to be a count of all combinations of topics/A and tags/B.

Final result for individual piece example from above (option 1):

```
Topics/A Tags/B Count
   AA     none    1
   AA      XX     2
   AA      XY     0
   AA      XZ     3
   AB     none    0
   AB      VV     3
   AB      VW     1
   AB      VX     2
   AB      VY     4
   AB      VZ     2
   AC     none    0
   AC      YY     4
   AC      YZ     1
```

Final result for individual piece example from above (option 2a, as seen below, or option 2b with columns and rows swapped):

```
       AA (none)  XX  XY  XZ  AB (none)  VV  VW  VX  VY  VZ  AC (none)  YY  YZ
   AA      1       2   0   3
   AB                             0       3   1   2   4   2
   AC                                                            0       4   1
```

I'm assuming I have to separate out the tags/B column so that it's something like:

```
   AA      
   AA   XZ
   AA   XZ   XX
   AA   XZ   XX
   AB   VV   VY
   AB   VY
   AB   VX   VV   VZ
   AB   VY
   AB   VZ   VW   VV   VY   VX
   AC   YY
   AC   YY
   AC   YY
   AC   YY   YZ
```

But, after this, I'm pretty stuck on what to do.
I tried looking up how to unpivot the above, but I would like some sort of formula or method that would be universal when the number of tags applied for a topic in a singular instance are generally unknown.
I've seen formulas that "flatten" the data, but I think they're designed for a fixed number of possible "tag" columns, which doesn't work for me.
I don't want to resort to manually entering formulas to flatten out the delimited matrix like:

```
   Topics (flattened)  Tags (flattened)
          =A2                =B2
          =A2                =C2
          =A2                =D2
          =A2                =E2
          =A2                =F2
          =A3                =B3
          =A3                =C3
          =A3                =D3
          =A3                =E3
          =A3                =F3
          =A4                =B4
          ...                ...
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula method. There's one part you might need a vba script for - let me know.

1. Replace all blanks in your csv with "none" (highlight it>cntrl+h>replace nothing with none)
2. Add "none" rows to your master list (let me know if you need me to write a macro that does this)
3. Use this formula with control + shift + enter
   `=SUM((A2=$A$17:$A$29)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,$B$17:$B$29))))`
   [image]

Comment: This would work if there weren't similarly named tags across topics, which I guess I misrepresented the data I'm working with by giving all tags a unique identifier. AA and AB could have something like VV as well as VV-L, VV-M, VY-L, etc. Maybe it's just a matter of coding all combinations from the master list as literally AA, AB, AC, etc.? Or is there just a simple addition to the formula that will only SUM if the two topic cells it's trying to count matches?